# How to record audio on Android without crash?

Tags: android, debugging, audio-recording

I'm developing on a Nitro HD with Gingerbread. I want to record audio and I experience an infinite hang while calling MediaRecorder.stop().

I know that my phone can record sound because I have an application that does it exactly.

I read the book "Android for programmers" from Deitel et al. and there is the example VoiceRecorder in chapter 16. Everything seems fine but the app hangs forever when it calls MediaRecorder.stop(). Also, the resource is not released and I have to reboot the phone to release it.

Here is the part of the code where the calls are done (see Deitel et al., "Android for Programmers", Prentice Hall, 2012, chap 16):

```
// starts/stops a recording
OnCheckedChangeListener recordButtonListener = 
  new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
  {
     @Override
     public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
        boolean isChecked)
     {
        if (isChecked)
        {
           visualizer.clear(); // clear visualizer for next recording
           saveButton.setEnabled(false); // disable saveButton
           deleteButton.setEnabled(false); // disable deleteButton
           viewSavedRecordingsButton.setEnabled(false); // disable 

           // create MediaRecorder and configure recording options
           if (recorder == null)
              recorder = new MediaRecorder(); // create MediaRecorder 
           recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
           recorder.setOutputFormat(
              MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
           recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
           recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(16); 
           recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);

           try 
           {
              // create temporary file to store recording
              File tempFile = File.createTempFile(
                 "VoiceRecorder", ".3gp", getExternalFilesDir(null));

              // store File as tag for saveButton and deleteButton 
              saveButton.setTag(tempFile);
              deleteButton.setTag(tempFile);

              // set the MediaRecorder's output file
              recorder.setOutputFile(tempFile.getAbsolutePath());
              recorder.prepare(); // prepare to record   
              recorder.start(); // start recording
              recording = true; // we are currently recording
              handler.post(updateVisualizer); // start updating view
           } // end try
           catch (IllegalStateException e) 
           {
              Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
           } // end catch 
           catch (IOException e) 
           {
              Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
           } // end catch               
        } // end if
        else
        {
           recorder.stop(); // stop recording
           recorder.reset(); // reset the MediaRecorder
           recording = false; // we are no longer recording
           saveButton.setEnabled(true); // enable saveButton
           deleteButton.setEnabled(true); // enable deleteButton
           recordButton.setEnabled(false); // disable recordButton
        } // end else
     } // end method onCheckedChanged
  }; // end OnCheckedChangedListener
```

In a debug session, the "else" scope is entered but it hangs on its first (stop()) line.

I repeat, I know the phone and its OS are correct because another app works correctly. So, do you have any idea on how to solve this problem, a work around maybe?

Thanks!

**EDIT** When the recorder is started(), there is a handler that is executed at each 50ms to display a graph of the amplitude of the sound. The method recorder.getMaxAmplitude() always returns 0. Maybe this is the symptom of a badly initialized MediaRecorder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument of setAudioEncodingBitRate() might be too low.

[what is good setAudioEncodingBitRate on record voice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645850/what-is-good-setaudioencodingbitrate-on-record-voice)

Hope that's help.

Comment: Could be useful.I'll try it as soon as possible.

Comment: Well, that help. The system hangs no longer since I changed .3gp to .mp4 and 16 to 96000. But, it seems to hangs in the code at some point elsewhere because I can not stop the recording and I cannot get the temporary file recorded. Something else to explore when I'll find few minutes.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot! Now it works fine (other problems but I will open other questions). I used `recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);` I didn't specified the encoding bitrate but specified the sampling rate with `Recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(8000);`.

Comment: OK, I had to set the recording bit rate to 12.2 kbs explicitely (`Recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate( 12200 );` to be able to read/listen the file in Linux...

Answer (score 0):

You could have a null recorder at that spot.  You're not creating a new MediaRecorder() if you enter the else case of isChecked.

So, 2 things:

The API docs state that if you call stop() before start you'll throw a RuntimeException And if you fail to record anything you'll throw an IllegalStateException.

Check recorder before calling stop:

```
if (recorder != null) {
    recorder.stop();
    // some recorder stuff here
}
```

Comment: Well, the Recorder is not supposed to be null because it was previously started in the "if (isChecked)". In this scope, it is instanciated if it is null. So can it be lost (become null) between the start() and the stop()?